# How to count rows and Columns of excel sheet in Java

Tags: java, excel, xssf

Is there a way to count the number of rows and columns in an excel table in Java?  I am using XSSF workbook to import and parse the data into the program. . There are no empty cells until after the last row or column. For example if there was a table that was 5 rows and 3 columns, cell b2 would not be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSSF sheet has a method called [getPhysicalNumberOfRows()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getPhysicalNumberOfRows()) to get what looks like you want for rows, but I don't know about columns.

Comment: any method to get the current row ??